# Xcode 7.1: Failed to build project <Project Name> for scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, xcode7

Has anyone faced this issue?

Been stuck trying to do a simple Xcode Bot integration with my simple project. Keeps coming back with this error that the bot wasn't able to build the project. From what I see, the scheme is just a normal scheme with the Unit Tests and UI Unit Tests. Bot is enabled Periodically and the Devices currently I've only set it to All Simulators (tried with others but it didn't work too). One thing I notice was when remove the Tests from the Scheme the Integration worked fine.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was finally able to find the issue for this! Removing UI Tests initially showed that the integration was working fine. It seems that as Xcode UI Testing is only available on iOS9, the automated building would fail (without telling you the true reason) when testing on older simulators/devices. To overcome this I configured two separate bots:

1. Test for Unit Test Cases
2. Test for UI Test Cases (specifically on iOS 9 simulators / devices)

Hope this solves the issue for anyone else facing it!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that in automatically updating Xcode it uninstalls the iOS 9.0 simulator and replaces it with the iOS 9.1 simulator. It doesn't think to update the build settings on the Xcode server.

So to fix the problem, you have to manually open Xcode on your server, it then prompts you to install several items which you need to do. Then go to xcode preferences > Downloads and you can reinstall the iOS 9.0 simulator.

Comment: Hmm I've tried reinstalling the entire Xcode that didn't do the trick too

Comment: Nope not yet unfortunately. Will try your suggestion again when I get at my comp

Comment: still no luck with it. have tried fully removing Xcode and reinstalling all the simulators but the issue still persists